# How to show Price Countdown in home page?

Tags: home

I install [**Price Countdown**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/price-countdown.html) in my store and it just shows in product page but I want to show it in home page in box of sales product but I don't know which part of the extension's code show the countdown.

Any body can help me?